# TextField with initial value inside StreamBuilder

Tags: controller, flutter, textfield, default-value, stream-builder

We are creating an user's editing data page, so the textfield already comes filled with the user data and users can change and save it... The problem is that when I start to enter character into textfield, the cursor get lost, every character that I enter (from the device keyboard), the cursor goes to the first character... and if I remove the controller with my initial value, it works fine, but then I can not have my textfield filled with the users data.

Code sample:

```
child: StreamBuilder<String>(
    stream: _bloc.myStream,
    builder: (context, snap) => TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'example',
            labelText: 'Name',
            errorText: snap.error,
          ),
          onChanged: _bloc.updateMyStream,
          controller: TextEditingController(text: snap.data),
        ),
  ),
```

Comment: Your are stuck in loop - you enter data in TextField - it calls - `onChanged: _bloc.updateMyStream` - which update the Stream - which  again update data `stream: _bloc.myStream` gets new data then it goes to `controller: TextEditingController(text: snap.data)` which update the textfield again. hence your cursor goes to the first character again.

Comment: I Alson tried:

child: StreamBuilder<String>(
        stream: _bloc.myInitialValueStream,
        builder: (context, snap) => TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                errorText: snap.error,
              ),
              onChanged: _bloc.updateAnotherStream,
              controller: TextEditingController(text: snap.data),
            ),
      ),

then only the first time that I focus on the textfield, the cursor goes to the first character....

Comment: Instead of Directly returning the TextField - use condition if (snap.hasDate){return TextField...} cuz Stream initial Data is Null always. check - https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html

Comment: anmol.majhail, did it but nothing changed... the cursor still goes to the first character.... =/

Comment: what if you comment `onChanged: _bloc.updateMyStream,`

Comment: tried and nothing changes...

Comment: @ViniciusSossella can you help me with the solution. I am stuck in similar situation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Whenever you need to update your TextController text, to be able to edit it you need to fix your cursor position like this

```
textController.value = textController.value.copyWith(text:<NEW_VALUE>,);
```

replace  NEW_VALUE by the new text .

Comment: @ViniciusSossella what was your final solution for the example? I didnt get it.

Comment: Can you give a more detailed example? I am in a similar situation and unable to figure out.

Comment: it places cursor position to beginning when I type

Comment: the cursor position goes to the middle of the word, or sometimes immediately after the first letter, but never at the end like it should be

Answer (score 10):

@XoXo here are the full code, But you can do it in your way.

```
TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

return StreamBuilder<String>(
    stream: _bloc.myStream,
    builder: (context, snap) {
      _controller.value =
          _controller.value.copyWith(text: snap.data);

      return TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'ex: Centro',
          labelText: 'Bairro',
          errorText: snap.error,
        ),
        onChanged: _bloc.updateMyStream,
        controller: _controller,
      );
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

To have your cursor to the end of your text, when you edit your text controller, think about to also edit your selection controller like so :

```
controller.text = newText;
controller.selection = controller.selection.copyWith(baseOffset: newText.length, extentOffset: newText.length);
```

Hope it helped !

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks alot.