# TextField cursor not moving when setting text using controller in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using `StreamBuilder` to listen to changes to the TextField and update the TextField errorText accordingly. But now I also want to set some text to the TextField through the snapshot data. But the cursor is not moving at all when typing. Below is my code:

```
Widget goalField() {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: _bloc.goalMessage,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
          return TextField(
            controller: TextEditingController(text: snapshot.data),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
            maxLines: 3,
            onChanged: _bloc.changeGoalMessage,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Enter your goal here", errorText: snapshot.error),
          );
        });
  }
```

Its going in a loop. How can I fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53683436/10269042

Comment: Thanks it worked @anmol.majhail

Comment: Don’t touch onChanged when you specify a controller. The controller has addListener method to detect changes.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the solution suggested in the comments using `_textEditingController.value.copyWith(text: snapshot.data)`, but the cursor seems to be placed at the start of the text every time the value displayed on the TextField is updated.

[image: Demo 1 using text controller value]

What worked for me is setting an offset on the TextField using `_textEditingController.selection.copyWith(extentOffset: _textEditingController.text.length)`.

[image: Demo 2 using selection offset]

Here's how you can apply this on your code snippet.

```dart
var _textEditingController = TextEditingController();

...

StreamBuilder(
    stream: _bloc.goalMessage,
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
        _textEditingController.text = snapshot.data;
        _textEditingController.selection = _textEditingController.selection.copyWith(extentOffset: _textEditingController.text.length);
        return TextField(
            controller: _textEditingController,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
            maxLines: 3,
            onChanged: _bloc.changeGoalMessage,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Enter your goal here", errorText: snapshot.error),
        );
    },
);
```